# Should I store different types user activity data under the same prefix in AWS S3 or use a different prefix for each category of event?

Tags: sql, database, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Should I store different types user activity data such as login, activity, payment under the same prefix / path in AWS S3 or use a different prefix for each category of event?

For example,
loginEvents/
paymentEvents/
interactionEvents/

I am using Firehose to stream events and save in s3. After that, I would use Athena to query. Athena would work with either case (one prefix or multiple prefixes) but which way is a better practice?

Saving all under one prefix would reduce query time because I wouldn't need table join during Athena query?
Saving data under different prefixes seem to organize the data more systematically?

Comment: say out of 100 queries that you will issue how many of them will involve multiple i.e, all partitions? If it is say maybe 30% then you are good otherwise you are not. Also what is the average file size in your case?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the queries that will run. If you most often include user activity in the `where` clause, then you will have better performance and lower query cost if you write the events in separate locations and use them as partitions. On the other hand, having lots of partitions will slow down your queries.

Comment: I think most of my queries involve multiple partitions. For example, users who hasn't logged in for 2 weeks but have used certain functions before. Another example would be user who has used a certain function and visited payment page but failed to check out. If my queries span multiple partitions, it would be better not to partition them, right?